# Get specific row from a random list by identifier

Tags: mysql

I have a simple table:

```
 ID | name
============
  1 | Foo
  2 | Bar
  3 | Loo
  4 | Zoo
  5 | Car
```

To get one random row I can use `RAND()`

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Now I like to select one random entry with an "identifier" which helps me to get always the same result.

Here are some examples to explain my needs better:

**identifier = 9876**

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE ORDER BY ??? = "9876" LIMIT 1
// result 

  ID | name
============
  5  | Car
```

**identifier = 363**

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE ORDER BY ??? = "363" LIMIT 1
// result 

  ID | name
============
  3  | Loo
```

**identifier = 13537**

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE ORDER BY ??? = "13537" LIMIT 1
// result 

  ID | name
============
  3  | Loo
```

As you can see the last second two results are the same even with a different identifier.

Requirements / Pre conditions:

- The identifier is a positiv integer.
- It should always return a row
- If there are new entries in the table the result can be different.

I was playing with `(FLOOR(1+RAND(table.ID)*100 )) = $identifier` in the order clause but never got the desired result.

Comment: @RaymondNijland I think the request is to have a seed (identifier) that would always return the same "random" result given a specific input. RAND() supports a seed (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand). http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4d65fd/24 is an example that shows this working.

Comment: Yes, a "seed" sounds more what it is. Maybe I have to think more out of the box but since I need a random result I guess `RAND()` is what I need. Although with the seed it's no longer random!?

Comment: @Xaver Could you generate a random number in your application and use that as a seed? I can't see another way to achieve what you want--needing to get the same result for a "random" selection is exactly what the seed does.

Comment: @RaymondNijland A given row can be selected for more than one seed number. E.g. "bar" in http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4d65fd/30

Comment: yes your right @StuBez i checked the manual for this using a seed within the `RAND()` function...i was thinking the larger numbers then table `COUNT(*)` as seed within the `RAND()` would mess up the `RAND()` function but it works fine http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4d65fd/35 don't know what i was thinking geuss i need some coffee

Comment: the seed or identifier is an ID from another table and known. although it should be able to increment it or “prefix” it to get a different row if needed